# APK size increased when updating androidx libraries?

Tags: android, androidx

I updated these dependencies from `1.0.0`:

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.1.0-rc01'
```

**APK size increased by 80 kB. Why?** I thought Google was aiming for *less* footprint for `androidx`.

(Note that I have applied all possible tricks to reduce the size of the APK.)

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: Good point. Maybe I should ask Google directly. Anyway, I would expect code/resource shrinking to take care of any new *unused* bloat.